# Onscroll not working

Tags: javascript

There's an onscroll event [here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/restaurants/gastropubs/the-greyhound-brentwood-487.html) on the top nav which isn't working and I'm not sure why.

The small search icon shouldn't be visible until it scrolls.

Here's a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/KEjfe/).

This is the js placed at the end of the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("body").scroll( function() {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( value > 120 )
        $("#topSearchIcon").css("display", "block");
    else
        $("#topSearchIcon").css("display", "none");
});
</script>
```

And part of the html:

```
<li id="topSearchIcon"><a href="#"><img width=20" height=20" src ="/images/searchicon.png" /></a></li>
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Make sure when the code is execute, `body` is already loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `$(document).scroll` instead, this should work.

Have a look at my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7sW84/1/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).scroll( function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 120) {
            $("#topSearchIcon").css("display", "block");
        }
        else {
            $("#topSearchIcon").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
</script>
```

If it still doesn't work, try to wrap it with `$(document).ready(function() {};`.

And don't forget to hide the `#topSearchIcon` by default.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work either unfortunately and I need the id really.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to wrap your script with ready().

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").scroll( function() {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( value > 120 )
        $("#topSearchIcon").css("display", "block");
    else
        $("#topSearchIcon").css("display", "none");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

$(document).scroll works for me on your page if you type this into the console and hit enter:

```
$(document).scroll( function() {
  var value = $(this).scrollTop();
  if ( value > 120 )
    $("#topSearchIcon").css("display", "block");
  else
    $("#topSearchIcon").css("display", "none");
});
```

The other change you should make is to set display: none; in your css for: "#topSearchIcon" so its hidden by default.